# Using *ngIf with routerlink

Tags: angular, auth0, routerlink

How would I implement "ngif" to a routerlink instead of creating a button?

example: `*ngIf="auth.isAuthenticated()" (click)="auth.logout()"`

To: `<a [routerLink]="['/']">Logout`

Comment: What's the purpose of combining `*ngIf` with `routerLink`. Sounds weird to me. How is the button related?

Comment: I'm using Auth0 for authentications and I'm using a template that already has a routerlink logout link. Instead of creating an actually button, I want to implement into the routerlink. Example of login button that came from Auth0's guide '<button *ngIf="!auth.isAuthenticated()" (click)="auth.logout()" type="button" class="btn btn-primary></button>'

Comment: Ouch, I mixed up `routerLink` with `router-outlet`. So what is actually the problem with `routerLink` and `*ngIf`? Btw. calling a function in view bindings like `*ngIf="auth.isAuthenticated()"` is prone to cause serious performance issues if `auth.isAuthenticated()` is doing some actual work (instead of perhaps just returning a value from a field). `auth.isAuthenticated` will be called very frequently (every time Angular runs change detection). It would be better to use an `Observable` that emits the new value when the value changed.

Comment: event bindings like `(click)="auth.logout()"` are perfectly fine of course

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
<span  *ngIf="auth.isAuthenticated()"><a [routerLink]="['/']">Logout</a></span>
```

Comment: Get an error "already closed by another tag" and just loops the page. I'm using an Angular admin template and here is an example:

Comment: <li>
                    <a [routerLink]="['/']" >
                      <i class="ti-layout-sidebar-left"></i> Logout
                    </a>
                  </li>

Comment: `routerLink="/"` is the same as `[routerLink]="['/']"`

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Thanks explain about how it can cause performance issues. I agree since I now see that sometime the page loads certain functions randomly. I just keep it simple and link it back to the authentication 's page as it replace "login" with "logout".  '<a [routerLink]="['/authentication/login']">'   '<button *ngIf="auth.isAuthenticated()" (click)="auth.logout()" type="button"></button>'

Answer (score 0):

You can put `ngIf` on any element. In your case `<a *ngIf="auth.isAuthenticated()" [routerLink]="['/']">Logout</a>` should work fine.

Comment: I try that and it just loops and keeps reloading the page. Error: "Cannot read property 'isAuthenticated' of undefined".

Comment: That means auth is not initialized in your component.

Comment: In this case `auth?.isAuthenticated()` would help to get rid of the error